# How exactly dependent pattern matching works?

Tags: agda, dependent-type

Dependent pattern matching on `x` allows us to, given an implementation of `P(...)` for each possible value of `x` on the respective case, prove `P(x)`. For example:

```
λ (P : *)
λ (T : P True)
λ (F : P False)
λ (b : Bool)
case b as x returns P(x)
    True => T
    False => F
```

Here, the compiler expects `P(True)` on the first branch, `P(False)` on the second one, and the whole expression then has type `P(b)`. Thus, my `case b as x returns P ...` expression should, in theory, substitute Agda's pattern-matching. But that's not true: Agda's matching also gives you information about previous arguments.

```
foo : (b : Bool) -> IsTrue b -> ...
foo .true ItIsTrue = ...
```

Here, pattern-matching on `IsTrue b` generated the information that `b = true`, allowing us to skip the pattern `b = false`. That was not covered on my syntax. **How, precisely, Agda deals with that extra information and when it knows we can avoid a pattern because of it? Would it be possible to extend my atomic `case of` syntax in a way that does the same that Agda's dependent pattern-matching does?**

Comment: Apart from general pointers on dependent pattern matching, let me point out (1) GADTs (in Haskell etc.) are in many ways similar to dependent pattern matching. (2) they have a case-style syntax, but they still give info on previous arguments — in your case example, the typechecker would know that `b` is `true`, and consider this in typechecking, even tho this is not visible in the program. Agda's syntax is designed to show this info in the program text itself (tho this text is still compiler-generated via Agda's emacs-mode).

Comment: You're in luck, Jesper Cockx just presented joint work with Andreas Abel precisely on that topic! Paper: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3236770

Also this is not a programming question per se. https://cs.stackexchange.com would probably be a more appropriate venue.

Comment: Do you know about the match-expression in Coq?https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/extended-pattern-matching.html